# GAlib247 error in make

Tags: c++, g++

I'm getting one error when I try to compile galib247 in Ubuntu 14.04 32bits desktop edition. This is the error:

```
                                                                             ^
../ga/GA2DArrayGenome.C:292:71: note: declarations in dependent base ‘GAGenome’ are not found by unqualified lookup
../ga/GA2DArrayGenome.C:292:71: note: use ‘this->crossover’ instead
make[1]: *** [ex17.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alumno/galib247/examples'
make: *** [ex] Error 2
```

I edit makevars file uncomment the appropiate code block. This is the change I have made:

```
### Uncomment a block from the list below appropriate for the compiler and 
### operating system on which you are compiling.

# gcc3, gcc4
#  verified 28dec04 on linux-x86 (fedora core 2 with gcc 3.3.3)
#  verified 28dec04 on linux-ppc (yellow dog 3 with gcc 3.2.2)
#  verified 28dec04 on win2k-x86 (cygwin-win2k with gcc 3.3.3)
#  verified 10jan05 on linux-x86 (fedora core 3 with gcc 3.4.2)
#  verified 06mar07 on linux-x86 (debian with gcc 3.3.5)
#  verified 06mar07 on linux-x86 (ubuntu with gcc 4.0.3)
#  verified 06mar07 on macosx-ppc (macosx 10.4.8 with gcc 4.0.1)
CXX         = g++
CXXFLAGS    = -g -Wall
LD          = g++ -w
AR          = ar rv
INSTALL     = install -c
RANLIB      = echo no ranlib
```

I have not made any other change. This library have been tested in DevC++, but I dont want use this IDE.

Any idea?

Comment: The error is not from "make", it's from the compiler, so you should show the relevant parts of the C++ code.

Comment: Close voted as _'too broad'_, which should read as _'too specialized'_ here. Also note @JimLewis's comment. It's a compiler problem in 1st place. Also your tag selection needs serious overworking. Don't get me wrong please: It's perfectly OK you post questions and your found solution as answer along. But this one really needs overworking, to be helpful for future researchers.

Comment: Thanks for your aclaration @πάνταῥεῖ . I hope make better in the future, but when I ask one question, I dont off my computer and wait an answer, I'm continue looking and trying changes.

Comment: @jgd Well, you can easily improve your question and answer, by editing them a bit.

Comment: off-topic? I dont understand it. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Change makevars file adding -fpermissive in CXXFLAGS.

```
    # gcc3, gcc4
    #  verified 28dec04 on linux-x86 (fedora core 2 with gcc 3.3.3)
    #  verified 28dec04 on linux-ppc (yellow dog 3 with gcc 3.2.2)
    #  verified 28dec04 on win2k-x86 (cygwin-win2k with gcc 3.3.3)
    #  verified 10jan05 on linux-x86 (fedora core 3 with gcc 3.4.2)
    #  verified 06mar07 on linux-x86 (debian with gcc 3.3.5)
    #  verified 06mar07 on linux-x86 (ubuntu with gcc 4.0.3)
    #  verified 06mar07 on macosx-ppc (macosx 10.4.8 with gcc 4.0.1)
    CXX         = g++
    CXXFLAGS    = -g -fpermissive -Wall
    LD          = g++ -w
    AR          = ar rv
    INSTALL     = install -c
    RANLIB      = echo no ranlib
```

then

```
make clean
make
```